# Where am I wrong binding this?

Tags: c++, bind

This is my [attempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b7c0097c15622e1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Voice;

class EnvelopeMultiPoints
{
public:
    std::function<double(Voice &, double)> mCallback;

    void SetupModulation(std::function<double(Voice &, double)> callback, int paramID) {  
        mCallback = callback;
    }
};

class Voice
{
public:
    EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnvelopeMultiPoints;
};

class VoiceManager
{
public:
    Voice mVoices[16];

    inline void UpdateVoices(std::function<void(Voice &)> callback) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            callback(mVoices[i]);
        }
    }
    static void SetupEnvelopeMultiPointsModulation(Voice &voice, std::function<double(Voice &, double)> callback, int paramID) {
        voice.mEnvelopeMultiPoints.SetupModulation(callback, paramID);
    }
};

class Oscillator
{
public:
    double ModulatePitch(Voice &voice, double currentValue) { 
        // somethings with voice
        return currentValue * 10.0; 
    }
};

int main()
{    
    VoiceManager voiceManager;
    Oscillator *pOscillator = new Oscillator();

    int param = 100;
    auto callback = std::bind(&Oscillator::ModulatePitch, pOscillator, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    voiceManager.UpdateVoices(std::bind(&VoiceManager::SetupEnvelopeMultiPointsModulation, std::placeholders::_1, callback, param));    

    Voice voice = voiceManager.mVoices[0];
    std::cout << voice.mEnvelopeMultiPoints.mCallback(voice, 1.0) << std::endl;

    delete pOscillator;
}
```

I create a sort of Voice Updater "basic" iterator, which I can pass any kind of functions later. It iterates all voices and pass the function I need for that iteration.

But it seems I'm wrong on bind the `Oscillator::ModulatePitch` function to pass to the Updater?

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: are you allowed to use lambdas? Using `auto callback = [pOscillator](auto& voice, double d) { return pOscillator->ModulatePitch(voice, d); };` works for me. A general rule of thumb is to avoid `std::bind`, when you can use lambdas.

Comment: Have you considered replacing `std::bind` with lambdas?

Comment: using explicit type for `callback` will fix it.
`std::function<double(Voice &, double)> callback = ...`
But i cannot precisely reason why :)

Comment: just FYI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0 ~28:45 Problems of bind

Comment: on MSVC I can't do `auto callback = [pOscillator](auto& voice, double d) { return pOscillator->ModulatePitch(voice, d); }; `, but only `auto callback = [this](auto& voice, double d) { return pOscillator->ModulatePitch(voice, d); }; `. Why? I'm inside a class where `pOscillator` is accessible (public) :O

Answer (score 0):

As pergy wrote in its comment, if you use `std::function<double(Voice &, double)> callback = ...` instead of `auto`, it works. The reason is that it forces a conversion from an `bind` object to a `std::function`.

If you do

```
auto callback1 = std::bind(&Oscillator::ModulatePitch, pOscillator, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
std::function<double(Voice &, double)>callback2 = std::bind(&Oscillator::ModulatePitch, pOscillator, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
std::cout << typeid(callback1).name();
std::cout << typeid(callback2).name();
```

you will see that the returning types are differents. And in this case, the second `bind` tries to build its object using the second type (which does not work). I think there is an issue with the conversion operator (from bind to std::function) not being called by the external bind.